# Understanding Approximation

Tags: calculus, approximation, riemann-sum

Your friend manages to squeeze in one problem between her classes. She used her calculator to find $L_n$, $R_n$, $T_n$, and $M_n$ to approximate a definite integral and wrote down the results on a piece of paper. The results were:

```
            0.3676, 0.3212, 0.3412, and 0.2748.
```

She didn't write down the problem nor did she record the value of $n$ she used. But she did draw the function (over the relevant interval) on a paper. The function looks like this:

[image]

She wants help in labeling the data she recorded as a left-hand sum, a right-hand sum, a midpoint sum, and a trapezoidal sum. **Which is which? Explain your answer.** $$\\$$

I don't know if this is correct, but this is what I have so far:

I know $L_n$ is the largest overestimate, $M_n$ is the second largest overestimate, $R_n$ is an underestimate, and $T_n$ the second underestimate.

Thus I got:

$L_n$ → 0.3676

$R_n$ → 0.2748

$T_n$ → 0.3412

$M_n$ → 0.3212

Comment: This seems correct to me.

Comment: @rb612, does the shape of the graph help determine that in any way?

Comment: yes, the concavity determines whether the midpoint is an under or overestimate. This is concave down, so it will be an overestimate.

Comment: @AmR Also the left hand sum is an overestimate for decreasing graphs. If it were increasing it would be switched.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen, what about for Midpoint sum & Trapezoidal sum?

Comment: Depends on concavity, as rb said

Comment: @rb612 so wouldn't $M_n$ = 0.3412 since it's an overestimate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a function is decreasing: $L_n$ is an overestimate and $R_n$ is an underestimate.

When a function is increasing: $L_n$ is an underestimate and $R_n$ is an overestimate.

When a function is concave down: $T_n$ is an underestimate and $M_n$ is an overestimate.

When a function is concave up: $T_n$ is an overestimate and $M_n$ is an underestimate. $$\\$$ In your case, your graph is decreasing and is concaving down so $L_n$ is an overestimate, $R_n$ is an underestimate, $T_n$ is an underestimate, and $M_n$ is an overestimate.

$L_n$ = 0.3676, $R_n$ = 0.2748, $M_n$ = 0.3412, and $T_n$ = 0.3212.